# Dockerfile or Registry? Which is the preferred strategy for distribution?

Tags: docker

If you are making a service with a Dockerfile is it preferred for you to build an image with the Dockerfile and push it to the registry -- rather than distribute the Dockerfile (and repo) for people to build their images?

What use cases favour Dockerfile+repo distribution, and what use case favour Registry distribution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd imagine the same question could be applied to source code versus binary package installs.

Pushing to a central shared registry allows you to freeze and certify a particular configuration and then make it available to others in your organisation.

Answer (score 4):

At [DevTable](https://devtable.com) we were initially using a Dockerfile that was run when we deployed our servers in order to generate our Docker images. As our docker image become more complex and had more dependencies, it was taking longer and longer to generate the image from the Dockerfile.  What we really needed was a way to generate the image once and then pull the finished product to our servers.

Normally, one would accomplish this by pushing their image to [index.docker.io](http://index.docker.io), however we have proprietary code that we couldn't publish to the world. You may also end up in such a situation if you're planning to build a hosted product around Docker.

To address this need in to community, we built [Quay](https://quay.io/), which aims to be the [Github](http://github.com) of Docker images. Check it out and let us know if it solves a need for you.

Comment: Is this just shameless advertising? Or is quay a package that I can download and run myself? Where's the link?

Answer (score 3):

Private repositories on your own server are also an option.

To run the server, clone the https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry to your own server.

To use your own server, prefix the tag with the address of the registry's host.  For example:

```
# Tag to create a repository with the full registry location.
# The location (e.g. localhost.localdomain:5000) becomes
# a permanent part of the repository name
$ sudo docker tag 0u812deadbeef your_server.example.com:5000/repo_name

# Push the new repository to its home location on your server
$ sudo docker push your_server.example.com:5000/repo_name
```

(see http://docs.docker.io.s3-website-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/use/workingwithrepository/#private-registry)

Answer (score 3):

I think it depends a little bit on your application, but I would prefer the *Dockerfile*:

## A Dockerfile...

- ... in the root of a project makes it super easy to build and run it, it is just one command.
- ... can be changed by a developer if needed.
- ... is documentation about how to build your project
- ... is very small compared with an image which could be useful for people with a slow internet connection
- ... is in the same location as the code, so when people checkout the code, they will find it.

## An Image in a registry...

- ... is already build and ready!
- ... must be maintained. If you commit new code or update your application you must *also* update the image.
- ... must be crafted carefully: Can the configuration be changed? How you handle the logs? How big is it? Do you package an NGINX within the image or is this part of the outer world? As @Mark O'Connor said, you will freeze a certain configuration, but that's maybe not the configuration someone-else want to use.

This is why I would prefer the Dockerfile. It is the same with a Vagrantfile - it would prefer the Vagrantfile instead of the VM image. And it is the same with a ANT or Maven script - it would prefer the build script instead of the packaged artifact (at least if I want to contribute code to the project).