# Advantages of a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We can create Docker images and all push them to Hub without a Dockerfile. Why is it useful, to have a Dockerfile? What are advantages of it? Dockerfile creation is a process with high consumption of time and can made only by a human.
I would like to know what is the main difference between a base image based, committed image and a Dockerfile based image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dockerfile or Registry? Which is the preferred strategy for distribution?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18029045/dockerfile-or-registry-which-is-the-preferred-strategy-for-distribution)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Dockerfile` is used for automation of work by specifying all step that we want on docker image.

> A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user
>   could call on the command line to assemble an image. Using docker
>   build users can create an automated build that executes several
>   command-line instructions in succession.

yes , we can create Docker images but every time when we want to make any change then you have to change manually and test and push it .

or if you use Dockerfile with dockerhub then it will rebuild automatically and make change on every modification and if something wrong then rebuild will fail.

**Advantages of Dockerfile**

- Dockerfile is automated script of  Docker images
- manual image creation will become complicated when you want to test same setup on different OS flavor then you have to create image for all flavor but by small changing in dockerfile you can create images for different flavor
- it have simple syntax for image and do many change automatically that will take more time while doing manually.
- Dockerfile have systematic step that can be understand by others easily and easy to know what exact configuration changed in base image.

**Advantage of Dockerfile with dockerhub**

- Docker Hub provide private repository for Dockerfile.
- Dockerfile can share among team and organization.
- Automatic image builds
- Webhooks that are attached to your repositories  that allow you to trigger an event when an image or updated image is pushed to the repository
- we can put Dockerfile on `Github` or `Bitbucket`

**Difference between committed image and Dockerfile image**

**Committed image** : it commit a container’s file changes or settings into a new image.

```
Usage:  docker commit [OPTIONS] CONTAINER [REPOSITORY[:TAG]]
Create a new image from a container's changes

  -a, --author=       Author (e.g., "John Hannibal Smith <hannibal@a-team.com>")
  -c, --change=[]     Apply Dockerfile instruction to the created image
  --help=false        Print usage
  -m, --message=      Commit message
  -p, --pause=true    Pause container during commit
```

It is good option to debug container and export changed setting into another image.but docker suggest to use dockerfile [see here](https://docs.docker.com/reference/commandline/commit/) or we can say commit is versioning of docker or backup of image.

> The commit operation will not include any data contained in volumes
>   mounted inside the container.
>
> By default, the container being committed and its processes will be
>   paused while the image is committed. This reduces the likelihood of
>   encountering data corruption during the process of creating the
>   commit. If this behavior is undesired, set the ‘p’ option to false.

**Dockerfile based image:**

it always use base image for creating new image. let suppose if you made any change in dockerfile then it will apply all dockerfile steps on fresh image and create new image. but commit use same image.

my point of view we have to use dockerfile that have all step that we want on image but if we create image from commit then  we have to document all change that we made that may be needed if we want to create new image and we can say dockerfile is a documentation of image.

Comment: **Question**: If I push a new version of my image to Docker Hub, should you rewrite the `Dockerfile` to reflect those changes? My concern is if someone pulls the `Dockerfile` from my Github repo, they might not be getting the most up to date version of the image.

Answer (score 2):

The advantage is that, even if you do not have a shared image registry to which you could push your images, you still can exchange said images with a "recipe" (the [Dockerfile used by `docker build`](https://docs.docker.com/reference/builder/)), which is only a couple KB of text, and can be passed around very easily (light and small).

That declarative format ensure that you will be able to re-build an identical image, and allows reproducible result.

Comment: Adding to VonC:
Having the Dockerfile allows you to validate what you get (to some extend).
You should not trust every images that is on docker hub.

Answer (score 0):

Docker commit

Using Docker commit command approach to create new images is error prone, one need to remember and update image for small changes and commit every time.

Dockerfile

- Dockerfile provides the ability to automate all the steps with set
  of Directives which gets executed during build (refer docker build command) to create final image along with commit of the image.
- Dockerfile is use anywhere, everything configured and ready to run approach.
- Dockerfile can be shared with others and updated easily by others. It
  allows to change the image easily depending on the requirement easily
  like security hardening, add or update user details etc.